# What does the -d option do in update-manager?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

When I'm updating my distro and I type in "update-manager -d" what does the "-d" do? Does it mean download?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-d updates you to the latest development release, from the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/update-manager.8.html):

```
   -d, --devel-release
          Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible
```